# File cannot open when it has double spaces in file name

Tags: java, windows, exec, spaces, rundll32

I am trying to open image using java program which file name has more than once spaces. direct windows command is working fine, but when I execute via java program it is not opening.

direct command :

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll ShellExec_RunDLL "C:\Logfiles\Client_Logfiles\Attachments\1044\image2   Copy.jpg"
```

via java:(This is not working)

```
p_fileName = "C:\Logfiles\Client_Logfiles\Attachments\1044\image2   Copy.jpg"
String cmd = "rundll32.exe shell32.dll ShellExec_RunDLL ";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd + "\""+p_fileName+"\"");
```

But if file name has one space, it is fine and opening properly:

Please any ideas on this and appreciate your kind help.

Comment: Use ` \\ ` or ` / ` instead of ` \ ` in Java strings.

Comment: this file path is getting by reading the file, so if file name has single space, this command is working fine. :(. this issue happens only file has two or more spaces in file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you concatenate command.
To make it correct use array version of exec and use '/' instead of '\':

```
String args[] = {
    "rundll32.exe",
    "shell32.dll",
    "ShellExec_RunDLL",
    "C:/Logfiles/Client_Logfiles/Attachments/1044/image2   Copy.jpg"
};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
```

Comment: Yes, your solution works. great help and thanks a lot.

Comment: [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is preferred over Runtime.exec.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
p_fileName = "C:\\Logfiles\\Client_Logfiles\\Attachments\\1044\\image2   Copy.jpg"
```

Or

```
p_fileName = "C:/Logfiles/Client_Logfiles/Attachments/1044/image2   Copy.jpg"
```

Comment: That should always do the same thing (except if you print it)

Comment: this file path is getting by reading the file, so if file name has single space, this command is working fine. :(

Comment: this issue happens only file has two or more spaces in file name.